# Code within comments being compiled

Tags: compiler-errors, comments, smalltalk

I am trying to comment out all the code in my assignment.  However when I attempt to compile (or whatever is going on; I seriously don't know), there is an attempt to compile the code within the quotation marks.  According to the book that I am using, ("On to Smalltalk" - Winston), Smalltalk ignores the initial double quotation mark, all characters between this double quotation mark and the next double quotation and finally it also ignores that next double quotation mark.  Why is this not working here?

I've tried putting the entire code into one set of double quotations marks and the results were worse.

I am specifically using Smalltalk/X. I just want help with whatever is causing the commenting error.

The errors that I get when the code compiles are:

> ===>  Parser [error]: undeclared variable: Removes
>         when compiling/evaluating for UndefinedObject
>         while reading C:\Users\Discouraged\Desktop\blank.st
>         at or near line 3 [relative to chunk start]
>
> ===>  Parser [error]: undeclared variable: pop
>         when compiling/evaluating for UndefinedObject
>         while reading C:\Users\Discouraged\Desktop\blank.st
>         at or near line 4 [relative to chunk start]
>
> ===>  "[" unexpected. (missing ".", ":" or selector before it ?)
>         when compiling/evaluating for UndefinedObject
>         while reading C:\Users\Discouraged\Desktop\blank.st
>         at or near line 5 [relative to chunk start]
>
> ===>  unexpected end-of-input in String
>        when compiling/evaluating for >UndefinedObject
>        while reading C:\Users\Discouraged>\Desktop\blank.st
>        at or near line 1 [relative to chunk start]

The code:

```
" 
Build a stack based (RPN - Reverse Polish Notation) calculator for rational 
numbers

Smalltalk at: #maxStackSize put: 32

Object subclass: #Stack    
   instanceVariableNames: 'stackArray stackTop'
   classVariableNames: ''
   poolDictionaries: ''
!
Stack class comment: '
   Redundant stack class
'
!

!Stack methodsFor: 'initialize'!

new
   ^ super new.
!

init
   stackArray := Array new: maxStackSize.
   stackTop := -1.
! !
"
"
!Stack class methodsFor: 'manipulating the stack'!
"
"
Removes the top entry from the stack.
pop
   [self empty 
      ifTrue: [
         Transcript
            cr;
            show: 'Stack is EMPTY!';
            cr.]
       ifFalse: [stackTop := stackTop - 1]. 
    ]
 !
"
```

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to code Smalltalk using the fileout format, which is intended for logging and transferring code, not developing.  So it's no wonder you're frustrated. You should instead load the IDE and use the browsers to write your code.  Smalltalk IDEs are pleasant environments to code, test, and run in.

There are a few issues with your fileout.  For example, you can't nest comments ("s).  Also, you are missing a trailing period, have some mismatched comment quotes, and included a single ! in a string when it should be escaped as !!.  Here's a corrected fileout below.

But, above all, load the IDE and use it.  You'll find that doing your class assignments with the IDE will be much more enjoyable.

```
" 
Build a stack based (RPN - Reverse Polish Notation) calculator for rational 
numbers
"

Smalltalk at: #maxStackSize put: 32.

Object subclass: #Stack    
   instanceVariableNames: 'stackArray stackTop'
   classVariableNames: ''
   poolDictionaries: ''
!
Stack class comment: '
   Redundant stack class
'
!

!Stack methodsFor: 'initialize'!

new
   ^ super new.
!

init
   stackArray := Array new: maxStackSize.
   stackTop := -1.
! !

!Stack methodsFor: 'manipulating the stack'!

pop
"Removes the top entry from the stack."
   self empty 
      ifTrue: [
         Transcript
            cr;
            show: 'Stack is EMPTY!!';           
            cr.]
       ifFalse: [stackTop := stackTop - 1]. 
!
```

Comment: So you CANNOT comment out code unless the code compiles correctly without comment notation?

For example in Java if I typed
    System.out.println("I hate Smalltalk");
this is compiled

and
    // System.out.println("I hate Smalltalk");
this is treated as comment and not compiled

Does Smalltalk not behave in this way?

Also we are restricted SmalltalkX [link] http://www.exept.de/en/products/smalltalk-x.html .

Comment: You can definitely comment out anything, even code that doesn't compile, just make sure you properly close the comment. So if you're commenting out something with double quotes, remember that extra  quotes close the comment, so re-open it with a pair of quotes. That's basically the same thing as escaping " as "".  That's no different than open/close comments in any language. For example, `/* Yo, */ this is a comment */` is not valid in Java.  But since Smalltalk is best developed as individual methods inside browser windows, there's never a need to comment out large chunks of code.

Answer (score 0):

The fileout format is basically a transport format, which uses unescaped bangs (!) as record separators. "! !" (with a space in between) is an empty record. They are escaped by double-banging "!!" - no space. When such a file is filed-in, it is FIRST split into such records (language agnostic), THEN analyzed by the compiler. 
Thus, when starting a comment in one such record and "end" it in another, the compiler only gets half-chunks to compile and will complain.

There is actually some documentation on the fileOut format within the ST/X documentation, which you should read.

That is the reason, for editing chink-filout files in an external editor being a bad idea - you have to be very careful to double bangs and not break this record structure.

PS: I see your trouble, because the "stc" compiler (which translates ST to C), uses this fileout format as input. But this compiler is meant to compile filed-out code (from the IDE) for final deployment, not for development.